# Reorder column without using query in SQLite (SQLiteAdmin tool) table

Tags: sqlite

How to reorder column without using query in SQLite (SQLiteAdmin tool) table?Is it possible?

Comment: No..How to acheive it in SQLite Admin tool?

Comment: ah, I can't help you there, as I don't use it. But maybe specify this in your question that you want to do it in the sqlite admin tool (and the name of the admin tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the table from the left panel. From the menu, Table->Edit and just drag and drop the columns! Then click Edit.